# Why does this angularjs directive not show the bound document?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with a bound doc model from controller. But the directive does not show the document?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">TestApp:
    <div ng-controller="TestController as Test">Testdoc controller: {{Test.doc}}
        <br>
        <test-me ng-init="abc=123" my-model="Test.doc">Testdoc directive: {{myDoc}} | {{abc}}</test-me>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("TestController", function () {
    this.doc = {
        name: 'testname',
        id: null
    };
});

app.directive("testMe", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            myDoc: '=myModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

        }
    }
});
```

output HTML is still:

```
TestApp:
Testdoc controller: {"name":"testname","id":null} 
Testdoc directive: <missing output of doc here>| 123
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kx97y93k/14/

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Solution was not to call {{myDoc}} in html directly but inside a template.

```
app.directive("testMe", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>Testdirective: {{myDoc}}<div>',
        scope: {
            myDoc: '=myModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

        }
    }
});
```

See updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kx97y93k/18/

Many thanks to @Mr_Green for that hint

Comment: but what about that `{{abc}}` which was present in content before?

Comment: Yes because ng-init initializes the abc variable inside the new created  scope. Thanks for your help. That did it :-)

Answer (score 1):

add restrict : 'E' to the DDO, see below. Angular 1.2 uses restrict : 'A' if not explicitly set otherwise. For Angular 1.3 that became 'EA' and your directive would have worked. To make it work in your fiddle, change it as follows:

```
app.directive("testMe", function () {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope: {
        myDoc: '=myModel'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thx for that advice but after updating the jsfiddle still does not work.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct. I want to also add that you should mention the content in `template` property in `directive`. Not in html. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kx97y93k/17/). Now you should figure out why `{abc}` is not working :)

Comment: @DennisAhaus what do you expect to happen? Your directive is doing nothing.